# Convert onclick function to onload

Tags: javascript

This is the code which is showing the `pop up` on clicking it, but I want to active the pop up when the page is loaded.

Basically I have a tag Which is this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:introJs().start();">Show me The Demo</a>
```

And I want to active this code when the page is loadedenter code here.

I want to convert onclick function to onload function.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Edited - Snippet wasn't formatted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No One Give Me The Answer I Found My Own Answer which is

The javascript code is this which calls the a tag when the page is loaded.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
                <script>

                    $(document).ready(function(){


                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            javascript:introJs().start();
                          });
                        }); 


                </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no code from topic starter, so try something like this:

```
$(function() {
  introJs().start();
});
```

Snippet will be updated when **@chirayu sharma** will provide code.

**Updated snippet.**

Comment: No sir I have code in a tag and which is proper working. But I want  the code is active when page is loaded Please help me sir

Comment: where is `introJs()` function?

Comment: Here is the introjs() function